# Do triggers work for attachments object on insert event?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have the requirement to calculate the number of attachments for custom object.
So I have written the trigger on attachment where as it was not working on Insert event. I want to check is insert event work on Attachments or not?

Answer (score 0):

After Insert triggers are supported on Attachments and Notes. Please refer to this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181538&type=1

Below an example from the documentation link above:

```
trigger SetTitleToAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {

String Title;
Id pId;

for(Attachment att: Trigger.new){
    Title=att.Name;
    pId=att.ParentId;
}

List<Case> c=[select Id , Title__c from Case where Id=:pId];

//assuming one record is fetched.
c[0].Title__c=Title;

update c[0];

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.When  i am testing this trigger in lightning trigger on attachments is completely not working.So after analyzing got to know that we need to write trigger on contentdocumentlink object for attachments.Now trigger working for Insert event in Lightining where as trigger is not firing at all for delete event.Is this bug in lightning from salesforce?

Comment: Written Insert trigger event on ContentDocumentLink and Delete trigger event on ContentDocumnet.Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you're working with Files and not Attachments. Files work with ContentVersions, ContentDocuments and ContentDocumentLinks.

You want a trigger on a ContentVersion.